# The menu does not disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please tell me how to fix the problem with the menu.

When you hover over the PAGES item, the desired block is displayed, but it does not disappear if you move the mouse cursor away from the displayed pages block.

```
$(".link__mega-menu").mouseover(function() {
    $(".drop-down__mega-menu").show();
});

$(".drop-down__mega-menu").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".drop-down__mega-menu").hide();     
});
```

https://codepen.io/Dasha_Novikov/pen/NWPbeyw

Comment: you can do same thing with css also

Comment: @Devsi Odedra the block that I call is higher in DOM, so I can not access it through css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.hover` event instead of mouse event

```
$(".link__mega-menu, .drop-down__mega-menu").hover(function() {
      $(".drop-down__mega-menu").show();
    }, function() {
      $(".drop-down__mega-menu").hide();     
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this method does not work, the menu immediately hides when I try to hover over it. Look codepen

Comment: I have modified the answer, let me know if that works for you or not

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using different classes for adding the `.show()` and `.hide()` events. If you hover on `.link__mega-menu` you aren't hovering over `.drop-down__mega-menu` so you have to first move your cursor into the drop-down menu and then leave it again.